# DFS vs BFS in web crawler design

Tags: web-crawler, html, depth-first-search

I come up with an interview question that I would like to know your opinion about that. The questions are say that in designing a web crawler:

1) what kind of pages will you hit with a DFS versus BFS?

2) how would you avoid getting into infinite loops?

I appreciate if somebody could answer them.

Comment: I think this post answers the questions pretty well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356524/web-cralwer-algorithm-depth

Comment: But my question is that for what kind of pages we prefer DFS over BFS.right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Designing a web crawler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834808/designing-a-web-crawler)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 1) what kind of pages will you hit with a DFS versus BFS?

In most situations, I will use BFS algorithm to implement a spider because most valuable info I want to get from web pages doesn't have much link depth, otherwise I think the site is not much valuable to crawl because of the bad design.

If I want to get some specific data from **one** page and other related data from a few hops and at the same time I want to see the results soon after the spider runs, then I may choose DFS algorithm. Say, I want to get all the tags from stackoverflow. The tag page is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags). At the same time, I want to get who answer what questions in the tag. And I want to check whether the spider runs properly. Then I use DFS algorithm to get the data **tag-questions-answers** soon after the spider runs.

In a word, it depends on the usage scenario.

> 2) how would you avoid getting into infinite loops?

This question may be simple. Solutions are such as:

- Use **MAX LINK DEPTH**.
- Record urls that you have crawled and before emit a new request, check whether the url has been crawled.

I remember [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) seems could solve the second question. You could read its source code to search for a better solution.

Comment: Thanks @flyer . I got the idea from your answer.